# In Pine Script, how is it that my strategy net profit is 0 when I clearly see profit on the chart?

Tags: pine-script

I am experimenting a simple strategy for long positions, here are the results (more or less 43 pips of profits):

[image]

Here are the parameters of my strategy:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="My strategy",
calc_on_every_tick=true,
overlay=true,
max_labels_count=500,
initial_capital=1000,
default_qty_value=20,
currency='USD',
process_orders_on_close=true,
commission_type='percent',
commission_value=0.075,
default_qty_type=strategy.cash,
calc_on_order_fills=true)
```

I have also tried to rise *initial_capital* and *default_qty_value* but still very low net profit.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

**p.s**: here is the code of the entire strategy if you want to test it

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="STRAT MANU 1", calc_on_every_tick=true, overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, initial_capital=1000, default_qty_value=20, currency='USD', process_orders_on_close=true, commission_type='percent', commission_value=0.075, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, calc_on_order_fills=true)




///////////////////////////
// FONCTIONS
///////////////////////////
Entering(entry_cond) =>
    result = false
    if entry_cond and strategy.opentrades > 0 == false
        result := true
    result


print(txt) =>
    label.new(bar_index, open, txt, yloc = yloc.belowbar, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.black, size = size.normal)


GetPipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)



///////////////////////////
// CONSTANTES
///////////////////////////

GROUP_INDICATEURS = "Indicateurs"
GROUP_MACD="MACD"
GROUP_HA="Heikin Ashi"
GROUP_RSI="RSI"
GROUP_CCI="CCI"
GROUP_RANGE = "Range and debugging"
GROUP_VA_RSI = "Variables d'ajustement RSI"
GROUP_VA_CCI = "Variables d'ajustement CCI"

// variable qui determine si la bougie fait partie du "range" pour le debuggage

timeAndDateInputBefore = input.time(timestamp("21 Apr 2022 16:00 +0300"), "Date départ")
timeAndDateInputAfter = input.time(timestamp("25 Apr 2022 22:00 +0300"), "Date arrivée")
bool barIsLater = time > timeAndDateInputBefore and time < timeAndDateInputAfter



///////////////////////////
// VARIABLES
///////////////////////////


var float stop_loss = na
var float take_profit = na




///////////////////////////
// INDICATEURS
///////////////////////////

        
// Heikin Ashi
haHandle=ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,open)
haClose=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,close)
haLow=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,low)
haHigh=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,high)
haDeltaAbs=haClose-haClose[1] // diff abs entre les deux derniers close
//haDeltaRel=haDeltaAbs/(haClose[1]*100)  //

haDeltaRel = haClose/haClose[1]




// RSI
len = 14
//input(title="RSI Period", minval=1, defval=14)
src = close
//input(title="RSI Source", defval=close)
lbR = 5
//input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = 5
//input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = 60
//input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = 5
//input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input.bool(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input.bool(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=true)
plotBear = input.bool(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input.bool(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=true)
bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)
osc = ta.rsi(src, len)

bool rsi_crossed = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(osc, 50)) < 1





// Trade Entry
bool haEntryCondition = haDeltaRel > 1 and haClose > haOpen and rsi_crossed and haOpen == haLow

bool red_ha =  haOpen > haClose



// Trade exit
Exit_cond = strategy.opentrades > 0 and ( close <= stop_loss or ( close >= take_profit and red_ha ) )



if barIsLater
    strategy.entry("my trade ", strategy.long, when = haEntryCondition and not haEntryCondition[1])
    strategy.close("my trade ", when = Exit_cond)


// MAJ TP SL

if Entering(haEntryCondition and rsi_crossed and not haEntryCondition[1])
    stop_loss := close - GetPipSize() * 10
    take_profit := close + GetPipSize() * 20
```

Comment: The reason is most likely in `strategy currency = USD` for your strategy. Netprofit in GBP may be positive, but due to the difference in the GPBUSD rate at the time of opening and closing positions. This can be easily rechecked by switching the symbol's currency to USD (in the upper right corner, on the price scale).

Comment: Go to "List of Trades" and you will see why.

Comment: I think I found why I had so little gain. I think it's because I was only buying ~20 contracts on each transaction. But on the Forex we generally buy lots, a lot being 100 000 contracts